# Submitting previous versions to TFS version control

Tags: version-control, tfs, versioning

I have an application that is developed without any version control system so far, and I want to use TFS version control from now.

I have different copies (snapshots) of projects files stored at different times of project development and I want to store them in TFS repository too.

- Can I use single workspace and copy each version to that workspace
  and check in? Does the changes to all files captured automatically this way?
- Where can I submit time and version history for each stored version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have the project in its current state and versions of it from previous dates?

From my experience, it's best to check-in the current version in Tfs as you would do for a new project. This becomes your working copy and all future changes are checked-in/checked-out and tracked in history.

For the pervious version, create an Archive folder in TFS with sub-folders for each date when you kept a copy of the project. Check in all files of that version into the appropriate folder. This can be used for reference.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly an option. However I look for a way to submit versions from previous dates in one folder structure rather than creating many folders for all those previous versions. I think this will be much more neat and clean solution. Do you have any idea in this case?

Comment: The thing is that the history that TFS store would contain current date/time rather than original date/time. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Can I change that time with a tools or through command prompt?

Comment: Apart from time issue how can I achieve one folder structure solution?

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible out of the box or supported either. Have a read through this thread.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/82ac5a32-cf7d-4b69-a9ff-fc8baec45b8b/adding-backdated-history-to-tfs-sourcecontrol

Please note that after a while the old code is just use for reference and having them in Archive gives a good view of it.

Comment: You can starts checking in with the oldest first. Then checkout and checkin the next version and so on. Don't think there is a tool for automating that. But please see my earlier comment. 

After a while, you would be using history to reference changes. Something you can do with Archive folder approach.

Comment: That's right for few archives. But for many previous copies, it seems to be a lot of clutter and copies of the same file

Comment: I think one folder approach is a lot more than simple check outs and check ins, and when I replaced next version in the previous workspace by replacing the files, visual studio failed to recognize all change-set.

Comment: So the steps you need to take when you check-in the next versions is

1) Check out the entire folder
2) Copy the new files
3) Click on Add items to add new files (i.e. files which were not there in the earlier  version)
4) Manually Delete files which were deleted in the next version.

A bit onerous

Comment: Thank you. I missed checking out entire folders and replaced .sln and .csproj files which must be excluded. A lot of manual work.